# Dimension of span of a finitely generated subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

If $QA\subset V$ is the span of $A\subset V$, V- a vector space over the field $Q$, $A$ - a finitely generated abelian subgroup (and hence has a finite rank), then is $dim(QA) = rank(A)?$ I think since $A$ spans $QA$, any basis of $A$ has a corresponding basis in $QA$ and hence the statement is true? Intuitively, it feels right but not sure about concrete reason. A hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$ be a basis in $A$. Then it is also a basis in $QA$. Indeed, every element of $QA$ is a rational linear combination  of elements of $A$ and hence a rational linear combination of $e_1,\dots,e_k$. Let us prove that $e_1,\dots, e_k$ are linearly independent in $QA$. Assume that they are, $\lambda_1 e_1+\dots+\lambda_ke_k=0$. Let $q$ be a common denominator of all nonzero $\lambda_j$, and let $m_j=q\lambda_j$. Then all $m_j$ are integers and $m_1e_1+\dots+m_ke_k=0$, and hence all $m_j=0$ by the linear independence of $e_1,\dots,e_k$ in $A$.

Comment: I see. May I know why $A\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: Let $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ be the standard basis in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. The isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^2\to A$ is given by $(1,0)\mapsto 1$, $(0,1)\mapsto\sqrt2$. That is, $(m,n)\mapsto m+n\sqrt2$. Clearly, $m+n\sqrt2=0$ if and only if $m=n=0$.

Comment: True, but I am trying to show $rank(A)=dim(QA)$ and not $rank(V)$?

Comment: Agree with the isomorphism. Thanks.

Comment: In this case $QA=$ the linear span of $A$ $=\mathbb{R}=V$, because $QA=\{\lambda +\mu\sqrt2\}$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are arbitrary reals.

Comment: I forgot mentioning that the field Q is rationals, so $\lambda$ and $\mu$ would be rationals, right?

Comment: In that case, your assertion is true. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate that.